# Bootstrap Droopdown menu remains open after the page reload if the cursor is not moved from the hover state Edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dropdown, microsoft-edge

I am facing an issue while using the bootstrap dropdown. That works fine in Chrome and FF but in edge showing the issue. While I click a sub-menu option inside main menu the page gets reload and the corresponding page loads.But while clicking on the submenu if I do not move my cursor at all, after the page load the dropdown menu remains open until I move the cursor. 
I have tried almost all the solution,

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-nav" id="custom-top-nav">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a href="#/home" title="Dashboard" id="home" class="top-link" data-target="home">
        <span class="menu-item-parent">Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown"> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" id="dropdownBtn" data-target="performance"> A</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#/performance" id="performance" data-target="">
            <span class="menu-item-parent"> B</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show=!prodToggleEnabled>
          <a href="#/productivity" id="productivity" data-target="productivity">
            <span class="menu-item-parent">C</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show=salesFunnelToggleEnabled>
          <a href="#/sales" id="sales" data-target="sales">
            <span class="menu-item-parent">D</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show=salesFunnelToggleEnabled>
          <a href="#/funnel" id="funnel" data-target="funnel">
            <span class="menu-item-parent">E</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li ng-show=!modelToggleEnabled role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li ng-show=!modelToggleEnabled>
          <a href="#/models/contact_reason" data-target="models/contact_reason">
            <span class="menu-item-parent">F</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#/agents" id="agents" data-target="agents">
            <span class="menu-item-parent">G</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  
  </ul>
</div>
```

but really not getting the reason behind it. Please tell me what I should do.

Comment: Whoever is downvoting my question, I need to know what is wrong with the question. I am ready to accept the downvote only if this is a bad question not because of some people who could not answer it and just copied from somewhere else and be giving all the wrong possibilities. I hope stack overflow can remove such misleading contributor.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a

```
<div class="dropdown"> around the <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Also, You're missing an element with `data-toggle="dropdown"` (Not explicitly documented, but followed by all the examples and related to the warning in http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#callout-dropdowns-data-required )

Comment: Its a nested `li` and `ul` , so class `dropdown` is defined in the `li` .`<li role="presentation" class="dropdown">~

Comment: Hi I think you can see my code before answering it. What you have mentioned everything is there in my code.  Moreover this point is available https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17537. Thanks for all your effort.